# Gradle error while adding dependencies

Tags: android, gradle

I want to add a card view so that I want to add dependencies (got from google search) when the time of adding dependencies

```
   compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
```

[image: screenshot]

I am getting gradle error saying that

> This support library should not use a different version (21) than the compileSdkVersion (23) less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion.)

Comment: **This support library should not use a different version (21) than the compileSdkVersion (23) less.** : you need to add support lib version same or greater then compile SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used sdk version 23 for your project, but you use version 21 for cardview. If you compile with `cardview-v7:23` there should not be a problem any more. It is also a good idea to update the support libraries, if this does not help.

Edit: As I see the picture you posted, you can see that you use `23.1.1` for the other dependencies, but `21.0.+` for the others. Change `21.0.+ to 23.1.1`

Answer (score 1):

Change your `CardView` dependency to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
```

You cannot have a different compile SDK version to versions of the support library.

Answer (score 0):

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
```

Comment: @Al-Mothafar A code-only answer might not be a good one, but it's still an answer. I would recommend you this post about the LQPRQ: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)